# Convert java object with org.w3c.dom.Element to string and get error when convert back

Tags: java, json, xml, dom, jackson

I have wrapper class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Wrapper {
    private String id;
    private int number;
    private Element internal;
}
```

I have internal class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Payment {
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String account;
}
```

I create `Payment`, convert it to `org.w3c.dom.Element` and set to `Wrapper`. And after that I convert **Wrapper to string**  use **Json Jackson**

And after that I try convert the other way - **String to Object** And get error.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Payment.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

        //create paymant
        Payment payment = new Payment(BigDecimal.valueOf(100), "666");

        //convert to Element
        marshaller.marshal(payment, document);
        Element element = document.getDocumentElement();

        //set Paymant as Element to Wrapper
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper("123321", 987, element);

        //convert Wrapper to string
        String wrapperAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);

        System.out.println(wrapperAsString);

        //convert the other way
        Wrapper restoreWrapper = mapper.readValue(wrapperAsString, Wrapper.class);

    }
}
```

When I convert Wrapper to String I get this result:

```
{
    "id": "123321",
    "number": 987,
    "internal": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<payment><account>666</account><amount>100</amount></payment>"
}
```

But When convert the other way I get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem deserializing property 'internal' (expected type: [simple type, class org.w3c.dom.Element]; actual type: `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl`), problem: argument type mismatch
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":"123321","number":987,"internal":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<payment><account>666</account><amount>100</amount></payment>"}"; line: 1, column: 40] (through reference chain: com.pavel.Wrapper["internal"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:278)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at com.pavel.Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:139)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Change `internal` type to `Document` or `Node`.
2. Write custom deserialiser which will do the same as you in line: `Element element = document.getDocumentElement()`;

Custom deserialiser:

```
class ElementDeserializer extends DOMDeserializer<Element> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ElementDeserializer() {
        super(Element.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Element _deserialize(String value, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return parse(value).getDocumentElement();
    }
}
```

You can register it as below:

```
SimpleModule elementModule = new SimpleModule();
elementModule.addDeserializer(Element.class, new ElementDeserializer());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(elementModule);
```

But I suggest to stay with custom deserialisers for `Documen` - `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMDeserializer.DocumentDeserializer` and `Node` - `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMDeserializer.NodeDeserializer`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first option is not possible. But second is work! Thank you!!! BUt now I need apply this to kafka. I use `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer` and need add new `ElementDeserializer ` to it

Comment: @ip696, I'm not familiar with `Kafka` but try to find some customisation of `Jackson` for it. In case you will not find create new question with `kafka` and `jackson` tags.